# Save input value (text) but all have same class?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a Javascript page where an user can type in something in the first box and that thing will be replaced by what is in the second box. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8PesF/

Basically just a few text fields. Now, they all have the same class, but I need to save each field into an array. What I've been trying to do so far is this:

```
str1 = ["First String", "Second String"];
str2 = ["First replace", "Second replace"];
```

Then I can do my:

```
$("body").submit(function() {
    $("textarea").each(function() {
        for(i=0;i<str1.length;i++) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(str1[i],str2[i]));
        }
    });
});
```

That will replace str1 with str2 in each textarea for each value in the array. So I need to turn my input fields into the array, so the array will return what is inside the input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the looping function you provided is going to do exactly what you want (it may though), but this will solve the "I need to turn my input fields into the array" part.

```
var str1 = $(".string1").map(function(i, v) {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();

var str2 = $(".string2").map(function(i, v) {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvm3w/2/)

Comment: Found the problem myself, but it was pretty close to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8PesF/1/

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var strings = {};
    $('.string1').each(function(i){
        strings['str'+i] = new Array();
        strings['str'+i][0] = $(this).val();
        strings['str'+i][1] = $(this).next("input.string2").val();
    });
    console.log(strings);
});
```